# How to check for output table of called stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

Simple scenario. Stored procedure `sp_Task1` calls `sp_Task2`, and `sp_Task2` has an output temp table called `#Task2_Output`.  I want `sp_Task1` to take `#Task2_Output` and perform further transactions with it.

How do I get these two things to happen:

1) Make sure `sp_Task1` waits until `sp_Task2` is completed to move on to the next line of code.

2) How to check that `#Task2_Output` was successfully created from code within `sp_Task1`.

Comment: Which dbms? (Stored procedure implementations are too often not ANSI compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh Just to clarify, as Whirl Mind assumed, the dbms was in fact SQL Server 2005. Will note for next time to specify that up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't mention which DBMS, I assume it is SQL Server, since these kinds of situations usually arise there.

**For Question 1 :**

In SQL Server 2005, for a temporary table to be accessible to the calling stored procedure, you may have to use ##Task2_Output (that's right, two hashes) and not #Task2_Output, since temporary table names with two # prefixes are kinda global temporary tables available to the calling procedure but destroyed after their last use. However, you may have to look out for name name conflicts, if the table names are not dynamically assigned.

**For Question 2 :**

Get sp_Task2 to return a Return Code, with a RETURN statement. 
If the table creation succeeds, say, Return 1. 
If the table creation fails (known by checking `@@ERROR` immediately after the statement), then, say, Return -99.

In sp_Task1, call sp_Task2 like the following :

```
Declare @MyRetCode_Recd_In_Task1 int

EXECUTE @MyRetCode_Recd_In_Task1 = sp_Task2 (with calling parameters if any).
```

Calling a stored procedure with a ReturnCode = StoredProcName fashion, the return code returned by the sp_Task2 is received by sp_Task1. You can then check the return code in sp_Task1 to see if all is well.

Comment: incorrect. a regular single hash temp table will be accessible to the calling stored procedure.

Comment: @Jeremy only if it was created *by* the calling stored procedure, or some execution context that called *it*.  Local #temp tables that are created by a *called* stored procedure are deleted when that procedure exits.  The answerer here is effectively correct, as 99% of the time when someone says, as the OP has, "*has an output temporary table*", they mean one *created* by that procedure.

Comment: @WhirlMind Makes perfect sense! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct.

For Question 1:

> Make sure sp_Task1 waits until sp_Task2 is completed to move on to the next line of code.

There is nothing you need to do. Calling Stored Procedures and Functions is not asynchronous. If you have the following inside of sp_Task1:

```sql
... other SQL commands

EXEC sp_Task2;

... more SQL commands
```

then the "more SQL commands" will not execute until `sp_Task2;` completes (whether successfully or due to an error).

For Question 2:

> How to check that #Task2_Output was successfully created from code within sp_Task1

As it has already been stated, local temporary tables (i.e. prefix = `#`) created in a sub-process will cease to exist once that sub-process (i.e. the call to `sp_Task2`) ends. You *could* use a global temporary table (i.e. prefix = `##`), but then `sp_Task1` can only be called by one session/connection at a time, else you will run into a name conflict on `##Task2_Output`. But that can easily be avoided by simply creating the local temp table in `sp_Task1`. The name of that temp table has to be known as it will be accessed in `sp_Task1` after `sp_Task2` completes anyway. So no reason to not create it first:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Task2_Output (columns...);

... other SQL commands

EXEC sp_Task2;

... more SQL commands

SELECT ...
FROM   #Task2_Output;
```

And then you don't need to test for it anyway.

---

Additionally:

- If you do want to test for the existence of a temp table, use the following:

  ```sql
  IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Task2_Output') IS NOT NULL)
  BEGIN
    -- non-NULL value from OBJECT_ID() means the table exists
    ..do something;
  END;
  ```
- You really, really should *not* prefix stored procedure names with `sp_`. That prefix is reserved for system procs and is handled as a special case by SQL Server. It will first check for that proc in the `[master]` database and then in the local, or specified, database. Hence it is an unnecessary performance hit.
- Rather than using `@@ERROR`, using the `TRY` / `CATCH` structure is much more effective.