# How to check if a proc is already running when called?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027669/how-to-check-for-output-table-of-called-stored-procedure/28029377#28029377) where I ask about `storedproc_Task1` calling `storedproc_Task2`, I want to know if SQL (SQL Server 2012) has a way to check if a proc is currently running, before calling it.

For example, if `storedproc_Task2` can be called by both `storedproc_Task1` and `storedproc_Task3`, I don't want `storedproc_Task1` to call `storedproc_Task2` only 20 seconds after `storedproc_Task3`.  I want the code to look something like the following:

```
declare @MyRetCode_Recd_In_Task1 int
if storedproc_Task2 is running then
    --wait for storedproc_Task2 to finish
else 
    execute @MyRetCode_Recd_In_Task1 = storedproc_Task2 (with calling parameters if any).
end
```

The question is how do I handle the `if storedproc_Task2 is running` boolean check?

**UPDATE:** I initially posed the question using general names for my stored procedures, (i.e. `sp_Task1`) but have updated the question to use names like `storedproc_Task1` instead. Per [srutzky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577765/srutzky)'s reminder, the prefix `sp_` is reserved for system procs in the `[master]` database.

Comment: Is this for a single connection or across all connections to the database? If it is for a single connection you could use [`CONTEXT_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx?ppud=4) to keep track of the most recent run time. If it applies to multiple connections then you'll have to persist the most recent run time, and user if applicable, in a table.

Comment: For me, `sp_Task2` can only be called by other stored procedures, not by any user doing ad-hoc query.

Comment: Stored procedures always execute in the context of a database user, regardless of how calls are nested. It was unclear from your question whether you wanted to ensure that there is never more than one instance of `sp_Task2` running at one time, or if different database connections and/or users (e.g. one running a report while another is using a website that accesses the database) could use `sp_Task2` at the same time as long as neither of them tries to use the SP recursively or as a co-routine. Is the timing issue ("20 seconds") a red herring?

Comment: If `sp_Task2` is currently running, should any other proc attempting to call it wait for it to complete and then proceed to calling it, or proceed immediately to doing something else and never call it?

Comment: @srutzky It should wait for it to complete and then proceed to call it.

Comment: Ok, then I have a recommendation that I will. But I will also say that the question as it is currently phrased implies that it should not wait but instead do something else (as per your `IF running THEN --do something` ELSE call Task2`). This distinction should be clearer in the question as it might invalidate @Christian's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the desire is to have any process calling `sp_Task2` wait until `sp_Task2` completes *if it is already running*, that is essentially making `sp_Task2` single-threaded.

This can be accomplished through the use of Application Locks (see [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)). Application Locks let you create locks around arbitrary concepts. Meaning, you can define the `@Resource` as "Task2" which will force each caller to wait their turn. It would follow this structure:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Task2', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';

    ...single-threaded code...

    EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Task2';
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You need to manage errors / ROLLBACK yourself (as stated in the linked MSDN documentation) so put in the usual TRY / CATCH.  But, this does allow you to manage the situation.

This code can be placed either in `sp_Task2` at the beginning and end, as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Task2
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Task2', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';

{current logic for Task2 proc}

EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Task2';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Or it can be placed in all of the locations that calls `sp_Task2`, as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Task1
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Task2', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';

EXEC dbo.Task2 (with calling parameters if any);

EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Task2';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I would think that the first choice -- placing the logic in `sp_Task2` -- would be the cleanest since a) it is in a single location and b) cannot be avoided by someone else calling `sp_Task2` outside of the currently defined paths (ad hoc query or a new proc that doesn't take this precaution).

Please see my answer to your initial question regarding not using the `sp_` prefix for stored procedure names and not needing the return value.

**Please note:** `sp_getapplock` / `sp_releaseapplock` should be used sparingly; Application Locks can definitely be very handy (such as in cases like this one) but they should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Great answer, but how can you check if the procedure is running? I have an requirement that if procedure is running to not execute it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a global table as stated in the answer to your previous question then just drop the global table at the end of the procedure and then to check if the procedure is still running just check for the existence of the table:

```
If Object_ID('tempdb...##temptable') is null then -- Procedure is not running
--do something
else
--do something else
end
```

Comment: How do you avoid a race condition, i.e. two users see the table doesn't exist at the same time and both try to create it?

Comment: I think SQL Server would handle who won the race and who lost. The loser would get an already exists error so to handle this you would need to put the table creation into a try and catch clause.

Comment: Then why bother checking first? Just try to create the table and note whether or not an error occurs.

Comment: I don't know? My solution is just to the question that was asked. His original procedure would use a global table so if he wants to know if the procedure is still running and perform actions based on if it is or not then this would be an adequate solution for this.